# forEach a deeplist and tree to change the value of a key

Tags: javascript

I have a deep list and tree in which I want to change all the toggle keys to true, but, because of the structure it's hard to accomplish.

I wrote this function but it's useless I need one with forEach and it doesn't work

```js
function loopThruAforest() {
    return state.data.map((tree) => {
        console.log(tree) && loopThruATree(tree)
     
    });
    function loopThruATree(tree) {
      return tree.children.map((node) => {
        if (node.children !== null) {
          return  console.log(tree) && loopThruATree(tree)
        } else {
          return node.datum;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

```js
{
  "data": [{
      "datum": "String",
      "id": 1,
      "toggle": false,
      "children": [{
          "datum": "String",
          "id": 2,
          "toggle": false,
          "children": [{
            "datum": "String",
            "id": 3,
            "toggle": false,
            "children": []
          }]
        },
        {
          "datum": "String",
          "id": 4,
          "toggle": false,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "datum": "String",
      "id": 5,
      "toggle": false,
      "children": [{
        "datum": "String",
        "id": 6,
        "children": []
      }]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a to_visit variable to make a DFS:

```js
function loopThruAforest(data){
    let to_visit = [...data];
    while(to_visit.length > 0){
        let current = to_visit.pop()
        current.toggle = true;
        to_visit.concat( current.children)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to iterate objects and arrays. (But don't forget that you don't want to iterate strings.)

```js
function setTogglesTo(data, bool) {
  if (!data) return

  for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
    if (key === "toggle")
      data[key] = bool

    if (typeof data[key] != "string")
      setTogglesTo(data[key], bool)
  }
}

setTogglesTo(dataObj, true)
console.log(dataObj)
```

```html
<script>
  const dataObj = [{
      "datum": "String",
      "id": 1,
      "toggle": false,
      "children": [{
          "datum": "String",
          "id": 2,
          "toggle": false,
          "children": [{
            "datum": "String",
            "id": 3,
            "toggle": false,
            "children": []
          }]
        },
        {
          "datum": "String",
          "id": 4,
          "toggle": false,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "datum": "String",
      "id": 5,
      "toggle": false,
      "children": [{
        "datum": "String",
        "id": 6,
        "children": []
      }]
    }
  ];
</script>
```